# Why is only the numerator cast to float to obtain a float quotient while dividing two integers?

Tags: objective-c, c, clang

I am just starting out with Objective-C,and with C in general,so I suppose this is a C question as well.It's more of a **why** question rather than a **how** question.

I noticed that while dividing two integers ,the decimal part is rounded down to `0` even though the result is a float.The sources I followed suggest the following approach to deal with this:

```
float result = (float) numerator / denominator;
```

I want to know now **why** this works. Two things especially.**1)** if you have to cast the numerator, why don't you have to cast the denominator as well? **2)** Why can't you just cast the whole thing? What I tried first was

```
float result = (float) (numerator / denominator);
```

But this again rounded the decimal part to `0`. What is the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By promoting the numerator to float, you require the denominator to be promoted, as well. However, when you place the two in parens, then you are telling the compiler to do the work as integers **then** cast to float.

Answer (score 3):

Because in the first case, after the numerator is cast to `float`, the denominator is automatically promoted to `float` for the division operation.But in the second case, the result of the division is expected to be an integer since both numerator and denominator are integers.Any decimal part is truncated in the second case,and that's done before you cast the result to float.Hence only the first one will produce the correct result while the second will give you the truncated result.

```
  float sum=5/2; //sum will be 2.000000,not 2.500000
  float sum=5.0/2;  //sum will be 2.500000
  float sum=5/2.0;   //sum will be 2.500000
  float sum=(float)5/2; //sum will be 2.500000
  float sum=5/(float)2;  //sum will be 2.500000
  float sum=(float)(5/2); //sum'll be 2.000000 as cast is after integer division
```

Comment: Of course, there should be ` float sum=(float) (5/2);` in the last line.

Answer (score 3):

See the ["usual arithmetic conversions"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.8) in the C99 Standard.

Basically it says operands must be of the same type, and if they aren't they get automagically converted.

So, in `4 * 3.5;` the `4` (type `int`) gets automagically converted to `4.0` (type `double`).
In `(double)4 / 7;` the `7` gets converted to `7.0`.
In `4 / (double)7;` the `4` gets converted to `4.0`.
In `(double)4 / (float)7;` the `7.0F` (type `float`) gets converted to `7.0` (type `double`).
...

Comment: I can't help but think of LMG whenever I see your name.LMG is the slang for the Bren machine-gun in many parts of the world.Phat!Phat!Phat!Phat!Phat!,as boy-scouts we're allowed to squeeze it for 1 second each.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can also cast the denominator instead and you would get the expected result.

```
float result = numerator / (float) denominator;
```

This would work, but is unnecessary.

```
float result = (float) numerator / (float) denominator;
```

This performs integer division first (because the operands are both integers and they are wrapped in parenthesis), then casts the result as a float.

```
float result = (float) (numerator / denominator);
```

As long as you cast either the numerator or denominator to a float (or both individually), then the division will be performed using floating point division instead of integer division.